# Fotorama: Trying to center a fotorama div in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, fotorama

I have looked everywhere but can't find an answer to this. I am trying to use fotorama to create a photo gallery on a bootstrap web page but the fotorama div keeps displaying at the left hand side of the page. I've tried margin: 0 auto in various places, I've trying adding text-center and center-block classes but nothing has worked. Something in the fotorama js (I think) is causing the images to not center. I have tried to construct a js fiddle but am not quite sure how to work it - apologies.Any help would be much appreciated.
http://jsfiddle.net/q5ujq37n 
Here is my html code:

```
<div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
          <h3 class="text-warning">Thunder and lightning</h3>
          <p>text here</p>
          <div class="container-fluid" style="margin: 0 auto !important;">
          <div class="container-fluid fotorama" style="margin: 0 auto !important;" data-autoplay="true" data-width="50%" data-ratio="700/467" data-max-width="100%" data-allowfullscreen="true">

              <img  src="img/snow2.jpg">
              <img  src="img/snow1.jpg">
              <img  src="img/snow3.jpg">
              <img  src="img/snow4.jpg">
              <img  src="img/snow5.jpg">
              <img  src="img/snow6.jpg">
              <img  src="img/snow7.jpg">

          </div>
          </div> 
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add the following css code to fotorama.css :)

```
.fotorama__wrap {
margin: 0 auto; }
```